# Creating a Static IP Tool

Tags: powershell

As a junior tester in training, I've been tasked to create a custom tool that allows a person to input the desired static IP address.

The desired function: Have a screen/form that will require the user to input a Static IP address, Gateway, and DNS of their choice. Press OK and the form will automatically configure the IP address according to the input.

What it looks like: [Preview image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HO5vQ.png)

What it should do: [Preview result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0z4lF.png)

As I said I'm in training and have not much experience, so your guidance is much appreciated.

Code that I have created so far by combining and trying this out. Unfortunately I think I'm close but probably far from it. PS gives me the following error message:

```
At line:80 char:12
+ $adapter | New-NetIPAddress `
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (MSFT_NetIPAddress:ROOT/StandardCimv2/MSFT_NetIPAddress) [New-NetIPAddress], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Windows System Error 87,New-NetIPAddress
```

**The Code**

```
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = 'Static IP Tool'
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,300)
$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'

$AddHosts = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$AddHosts.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(55,200)
$AddHosts.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(90,50)
$AddHosts.Text = 'Ok'
$AddHosts.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$form.AcceptButton = $AddHosts
$form.Controls.Add($AddHosts)

$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(160,200)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(90,50)
$CancelButton.Text = 'Annuleer'
$CancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
$form.CancelButton = $CancelButton
$form.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

$IPlabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$IPlabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,20)
$IPlabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
$IPlabel.Text = 'IP:'
$form.Controls.Add($IPlabel)

$IPtextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$IPtextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40)
$IPtextBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20)
$form.Controls.Add($IPtextBox)

$GWlabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$GWlabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,70)
$GWlabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
$GWlabel.Text = 'Gateway:'
$form.Controls.Add($GWlabel)

$GWtextbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$GWtextbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,90)
$GWtextbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20)
$form.Controls.Add($GWtextbox)

$DNSlabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$DNSlabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,120)
$DNSlabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
$DNSlabel.Text = 'DNS:'
$form.Controls.Add($DNSlabel)

$DNStextbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$DNStextbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,140)
$DNStextbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20)
$form.Controls.Add($DNStextbox)



$form.Topmost = $true



$result = $form.ShowDialog()

if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
{
$IP = $IPtextBox
$MaskBits = 24 # This means subnet mask = 255.255.255.0
$Gateway = $GWtextbox
$Dns = $DNStextbox
$IPType='IPv4'

# Retrieve the network adapter that you want to configure
$adapter = Get-NetAdapter | ? {$_.Status -eq "up"}
# Remove any existing IP, gateway from our ipv4 adapter
If (($adapter | Get-NetIPConfiguration).IPv4Address.IPAddress) {
 $adapter | Remove-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily $IPType -Confirm:$false
}
If (($adapter | Get-NetIPConfiguration).Ipv4DefaultGateway) {
 $adapter | Remove-NetRoute -AddressFamily $IPType -Confirm:$false
}
 # Configure the IP address and default gateway
$adapter | New-NetIPAddress `
 -AddressFamily $IPType `
 -IPAddress $IP `
 -PrefixLength $MaskBits `
 -DefaultGateway $Gateway
# Configure the DNS client server IP addresses
$adapter | Set-DnsClientServerAddress -ServerAddresses $DNS
}
```

Comment: I think you also need to specify parameter `InterfaceIndex`

Comment: Perhaps better use [MaskedTextBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox) instead of normal TextBoxes. Together with casting the input to `[IPAddress]` in a `try{..} catch{..}` block can help making sure the user input is valid.

Answer (score 0):

You are very close!  Nice GUI!

You need to grab the `.text` values from each UI Element, like this.

```
#does not work
$IP = $IPTextBox

#works
$IP = $IPTextBox.Text
```

The first method doesn't work because that's making `$IP` contani the entire WPF Textbox object, with values like 'Position' and 'BrushShader' and other properties which aren't needed once the UI has done its job.

We don't want it because the `IpAddress` cmdlet doesn't know how to handle it.  The `New-IpAddress` cmdlets expect just the string or int value it should use.

`Dereferencing` the specific property with `$IPTextbox.Text` grabs the value from the box.
Do this for each textbox and you should be closer to your solution.

Comment: Hey Fox,  Thanks for your reply, but, I don't quite see the difference between #does not work and #works, haha, could you recheck?

Comment: Lol sorry! Check it now.

Comment: Thank you very much Fox, what you mentioned in your first paragraph instantly showed me the solution! Thank you very much again!